# SearchView filter for Recyclerview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

***Hello friends.***

I have navigation drawer with a menu item when clicking on each menu nav item, one fragment loaded, inside this fragments, I have recycled view items. Now I want use searchView filter for this items. I created a searchView icon in the toolbar, and write codes for  SearchView inside Adapter(setFilter) and etc, but nothing happen when writing names item.

this is my fragment.

**AfricaFragment**`

```
public class AfricaFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

public static final String AFRICA_FRAGMENT = "africa_fragment";

ArrayList<AsiaCountry> asiaCountries = new ArrayList<>();
ContentAdapter contentAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
//FastScroller fastScroller;
private boolean isListView;
private Menu menu;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //The parameter value of false indicates that container is to be used
    // only for the layout parameters.
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.africa_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    // fastScroller = (FastScroller) view.findViewById(R.id.fast_scrollview);

    isListView = true;

    loadDataBase();


    return view;


}

public void toggle() {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.grid);
    if (isListView) {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(2);
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_vertical);
        item.setTitle("Show as list");
        isListView = false;
    } else {
        staggeredGridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(1);
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_grid);
        item.setTitle("Show grid");
        isListView = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.grid_item, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    Log.d("Menu created", "grid");
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) 
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.grid) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Grid item touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        toggle();
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.search) {

        return true;
    }


    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void loadDataBase() {
    WorldCountry worldCountry = new WorldCountry(getActivity());
    try {

        worldCountry.createDatabase();
        worldCountry.openDataBase();
        Log.d("TAG", "Database open");
    } catch (SQLiteException o) {
        o.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Tag", o.getMessage());
    }
    try {


        Cursor cursor = worldCountry.QueryData("SELECT name, viewImage   FROM country WHERE continent ='آفریقا'");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    AsiaCountry asiaCountry = new AsiaCountry();
                    asiaCountry.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                    asiaCountry.setImageResourceID(cursor.getString(1));
                    asiaCountries.add(asiaCountry);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                worldCountry.close();

            }


        }
    } catch (SQLiteException o) {
        o.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", o.getMessage());
    }
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    contentAdapter = new ContentAdapter(getActivity(), asiaCountries);
    contentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    contentAdapter.setListener(new ContentAdapter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {


        }
    });

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(contentAdapter);


}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (contentAdapter != null) {

        query = String.valueOf(query.equals(""));
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    newText = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<AsiaCountry> asiaCountryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AsiaCountry asiaCountry : asiaCountries) {

        String name = asiaCountry.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (name.contains(newText))

            asiaCountryArrayList.add(asiaCountry);
    }

    contentAdapter.setFilter(asiaCountryArrayList);
    return true;
}
```

}

this my adapter.

**ContentAdapter**

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context context;
private List<AsiaCountry> item = Collections.emptyList();
private int mLastPosition = -1;
private Listener listener;


public ContentAdapter(Context context, List<AsiaCountry> item) {
    this.context = context;
    this.item = item;

}


public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ContentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    //Defain the view for take layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,
            parent, false);
    Log.d("Adapter", "Loaded");
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    AsiaCountry asia = item.get(position);

    holder.titleNameCountry.setText(asia.getName());
    Log.d("TAG", asia.getName());
    //  String imageFile = asia.getImageResourceID();

    holder.titleImageCountry.setImageBitmap(loadBitmapFromAssets(context, asia.getImageResourceID()));


   /* Glide.with(context)
            .load(loadBitmapFromAssets(context, asia.getImageResourceID()))
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                    holder.titleImageCountry.setImageBitmap(resource);

                }
            });*/

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(position);

                Toast.makeText(context, holder.titleNameCountry.getText().toString() + "is clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String nameCountry = holder.titleNameCountry.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetialsCountry.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", nameCountry);
                Log.d("CONT", nameCountry);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    // When items loading, must be show in animation, for UX better.
    if (position > mLastPosition) {
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY",
                        holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight() * 2, 0));
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "alpha", 0, 1);
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleX", 0.5f, 1);
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleY", 0.5f, 1);


        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorSet.start();

        mLastPosition = position;
    } else {

        ViewHolder.clear(holder.itemView);
    }

  /*  Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), asia.getImageResourceID(context));

    Palette.from(photo).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            int bgColor = palette.getDarkMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.black));
            holder.titleNameCountry.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);

        }
    });*/


   /* Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), country.getTitleCountry(context));

    Palette.generateAsync(photo, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            int mutedLight = palette.getMutedColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            holder.titleNameCountry.setBackgroundColor(mutedLight);
        }
    });*/

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();
}

//This method take getAssets from assets folder and compare with cursor.getString(1), and show in recyclerview.
@Nullable
private Bitmap loadBitmapFromAssets(Context context, String path) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = context.getAssets().open(path);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void setFilter(ArrayList<AsiaCountry> arrayList) {

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    item.addAll(arrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static interface Listener {
    public void onClick(int position);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView titleImageCountry;
    private TextView titleNameCountry;

    // Defian the viewHolder
    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleImageCountry = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
        titleNameCountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleCountry);
    }

    // public static class ViewHolder {
    private static void clear(View itemView) {
        ViewCompat.setAlpha(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.setTranslationY(itemView, 0);
        itemView.setPivotY(itemView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
        ViewCompat.setScaleX(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.animate(itemView).setInterpolator(null);
        Log.d("Animationg", "Loaded");


    }
}
```

}

Please help me :)

Comment: In your `setFilter` method `item = new ArrayList();`  `item.addAll(arrayList);` try that

Comment: @Yupi Thanks, this work for me. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setFilter in Adapter method, you are again creating object for the parameter you sent, So remove that and made the global item as empty

```
public void setFilter(ArrayList<AsiaCountry> arrayList) {

    //arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // remove this line
    item.clear(); // add this so that it will clear old data
    item.addAll(arrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

To reset the text we should handle in 2 place one is when user press ok, it will call onQueryTextSubmit, second way is user click back arrow at the top, So we should handle both,

```
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit() called with: query = [" + query + "]");

                    if (mAdapter != null)
                        // reset your complete list here

                    return true;
                }
```

Second place is,

```
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(mSearchItem,
                    new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
//                            Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemActionExpand() called with: menuItem = [" + menuItem + "]");
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
//                            Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemActionCollapse() called with: menuItem = [" + menuItem + "]");
                           // update your list with complete list
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is work too.I understand now what is my problem. Now I want when multiplication, all items show inside layout.Now I work with onQueryTextSubmit, correct?

Comment: I update the answer to reset the complete list have a look.

Comment: Hi, Could you update your latest code in your question so that I can check what's going wrong.

Comment: I updated. second place added to the project, but I can't add this codes to my question.

Comment: @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (contentAdapter != null) {

        query = String.valueOf(query.equals(""));
    }
    return true;
}, Is this the updated code.?

Comment: yes, this is. But I added query = String.valueOf(query.equals(""));

Comment: onQueryTextSubmit you want to display the complete list right..?

Comment: Yes dear,  after searching when press back button or clear text on search, items list must be shown. But when I search item, I want when to press back to the other fragments or when press clear text on search, all items shown.